# how to go back to 10.10

Tags: 11.04, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I upgraded to 11.04 and have so many problems with the interface (examples: can't change the time, I want the utility of the panels, half of GIMP top menu bar is rendered non functional, no weather and much more). How do I go back to 10.10 without risking file loss? My operating system and applications are in spanish.