# Upgrade 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How safe is it to use the “ubuntu+1”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55253/how-safe-is-it-to-use-the-ubuntu1)

Is it a good idea to upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 now or should we wait for some more time? are there any specific annoying things in 12.10 or it just works fine? I've heard that the dash is integrated with the amazon search results. Is that annoying?