# Ubuntu 12.10 hotkeys not working properly

Tags: shortcut-keys, 12.10

A couple of weeks ago, I ran a distribution upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10. Unfortunately, something has seemed to happen with the hotkeys on the system. At first, I thought that maybe this was just a glitch with the global hotkeys. That didn't turn out to be the case, as the custom hotkey I added into the Ubuntu settings works for my editor.

The only default hotkey that seems to have a problem launching is CTRL+ALT+T (Terminal). This wasn't such a big issue to begin with, because I can always just drag the Terminal to my launcher and launch it from there. However, I was on Chrome earlier and tried to do SHIFT+CTRL+DEL to clear the history and it failed. I then tried to do SHIFT+ESC, just to see if the hotkey for the task manager would work.. and it did.

I also thought it could be something with the "CTRL" key, since SHIFT+ESC works, but SHIFT+CTRL+DEL doesn't. That didn't turn out to be the case either, as keys like CTRL+ALT+DEL (logout) work perfectly fine.

Not quite sure how to go about this, and I haven't found any errors in any of `/var/log` that raises any suspicion.

Comment: Hi Sly, I suggest you read this 2 questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do & http://askubuntu.com/questions/55253/how-safe-is-it-to-use-the-ubuntu1

Comment: Not quite sure how those are supposed to help, when there's no log of anything happening that I can report on. Running `xev`, it catches the keys being hit perfectly fine. Again, there's nothing throwing an error for me to know what it is.

Comment: You are using an still developed version so, other problems can arise until the final release is made. I for one have 12.10 and have the SAME problem as you. For example this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1040954 or the one I posted here which is the same as yours: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1058486

Comment: Ah. I searched for a bug report on it the other night, but I guess I had it sorted by oldest first. All of the ones I saw had been "fixed", but I still hadn't received an update.

Comment: Yes same thing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in 12.10. I made a bug report here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1058486

which talks about the problem but this is still a development version of Ubuntu so we need to wait until the final release to see if this issue is solved.

Comment: Just an update, they pushed a fix out for this like 16-17 hours ago.

Comment: Let us test it then and give feedback.

Comment: Works perfect. Tested on laptop + PC.

Comment: Same here. I downloaded and tested it yesterday.