# Raring Ringtail upgrade

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How safe is it to use the “ubuntu+1”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55253/how-safe-is-it-to-use-the-ubuntu1)

If I open a terminal and  do `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` am I going to install Raring Ringtail if using 12.10 now? Is this advisable....is it safe.