# How to migrate from Ubuntu 11.04 to 10.04?

Tags: migration, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

(GNOME) I must migrate from Ubuntu 11.04 32bit to Ubuntu 10.04 32bit. What are my choices? I'm thinking about a clean install, so: 

1) save /home, /etc to a USD HDD
2) clean install Ubuntu 10.04
3) create the users (4)
4) delete the newly created users directories content (not the .* files)
5) copy back the users /home/* dir
6) if anything missing from /etc then that too.

Or are there any methods to downgrade to 10.04? (like we can upgrade with "apt-get dist-upgrade" after upgrading the sources.list file?)