# How do I go back to 11.04 from 11.10 following a failed install

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I tried to upgrade 11.04 to 11.10 and can't get it to work at all. Can I download an 11.04 iso image and re-install. My /home is on a separate drive.

I am quite new to Linux, 5 or 6 weeks and would really appreciate some constructive help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can re-install from a 11.04 CD-ROM. Before doing that, you could try a clean install from a 11.10 CD-ROM - chances are a clean install will be more successful than the upgrade.

(btw, I upgraded yesterday and I'm finding this upgrade the least troublesome of all... no hiccups whatsoever... wondering what went wrong in your case... did you install all updates before starting the upgrade to 11.10?)