# How do I downgrade to 11.04?

Tags: 11.10, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu 11.10 to 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-11-10-to-11-04)

I worked with Ubuntu 11.04 very well.
Then I was promted to upgrade to 11.10 which I did.
But 11.10 does not work for me.
The system gets stuck and behaves very badly.
So I want to go back to 11.04.
What is the easiet way to do that?

Comment: Did you not do a backup before you upgraded? I'm continually amazed at the number of people who still do a major upgrade without backing up their system first. There are so many easy to use tools out there like Clonezilla for taking a snapshot your system.