# Downgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to older release (8.10)

Tags: 11.10, downgrade, 8.10, release

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Is it possible to preform a full downgrade (not a reinstall) of Ubuntu? The reason is that I cannot get internet to work in a full installation (from livecd) for 8.10 Intrepid. I am thinking that since I will be downgrading, Ubuntu will keep/restore my settings completely after downgrading Ubuntu, therefore, I think I will be able to get internet working with 8.10. Thanks!