# How do I downgrade from 11.10 to 8.10?

Tags: 11.10, downgrade, 8.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I preferred Ubuntu 8.10 to Ubuntu 11.10. I would like to downgrade my computer, even if it means erasing all my files. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You would need to do a fresh install of 8.10. What problem are you having with 11.10 ?

Comment: Please note also that Ubuntu 8.10 has not been supported for some time and you wouldn't get security updates--the earliest version of Ubuntu that can be recommended for desktop use is currently Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.