# downgrading ubuntu from 11.10 to 10.04

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I have windows 7 installed on my C drive, ubuntu 11.10 installed on my D drive and then there are couple of more partitions with music n stuff like that. As per the present setting, when I boot into windows7, i am not shown the partition D (which has ubuntu in it). Somehow, the D drive is hidden in windows. Also, when I boot up, I have the option to select the OS i want to boot into :)

Now my questions -

1. Why am i not being able to see the D drive when I boot into windows?
2. I want to downgrade my ubuntu from 11.10 to 10.04 LTS due to certain reasons. How do i perform this downgrade? I have downloaded the copy of 10.04 in ISO format. I prefer a clean install actually, rather than the downgrade. Please let me know how to keep the windows safe in C drive, and then remove the existing 11.10 from D drive and then install the new 10.04 LTS into the clean D drive.

Comment: AU is setup as an question, aswer site and works best with 1 question being answered since you can only mark 1 answer as the approved one so please try to keep questions to 1 question!