# How to downgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and, well, it was fun to test but right now I just want to downgrade to 11.10 again. Is there a way to do this?