# UNdo an Update!

Tags: updates, software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I updated my Laptop Ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04, and I like 11.10 much much better! I originally put Ubuntu on my lap top by CD so I was wondering if I could just reload it from the CD. Will 12.04 be replaced with 11.10 if I did? I would love to have 11.10 back!

Comment: Can you explain why this is so as I find it curious. Do you require compatibility with a specific package? Had you said 11.04 I would have understood since that was the last version in which you could 'avoid' using Unity. 11.10 and 12.04 both have it, only it didn't work as well in 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but a safe and wizarded downgrade is not possible. The best solution is backup everything and make a fresh install.
You will find several topic around saying a downgrade is possible, but it's a manual operation that can be considered as equivalent as a fresh install after a backup.