# how to safely Uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 and reinstall 11.10

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 following the instructions here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades. But after the upgrade a lot of my image processing packages don't work some of their dependencies have been removed. Honestly there is not that much difference between 11.10 and 12.04. So please can someone tell me how to safely remove 12.04 and go back to 11.10 without losing documents, and source packages on my old Ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather lengthy HowTo [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto). It comes with its own disclaimer so I won't bother with that. BUT before you do that, read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/340467/is-it-possible-to-downgrade-ubuntu) why that is probably a BAD idea.

It is probably a much better idea to simply backup your files and re-install ubuntu if you can't figure out a way to make 12.04 work for you.