# How can I install Ubuntu 10.04 to replace 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I Would like to wipe hard drive clean and start over. How can I download Ubuntu 10.4 from Ubuntu web-site and install it instead of Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search gave me the the following site:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/

Answer (score 2):

Download the ISO from the [Ubuntu Site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/), burn the CD, and run the installation, choosing to replace the existing OS.

If you're sure you want to install it, you can hit a key as soon as the CD is read (when you see the install symbol at the bottom), and you can go right to the install without running the whole live CD first.