# How to completely uninstall 12.04 and revert to 11.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 11.04, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I am trying to uninstall 12.04 to revert back to 11.04 due to compiler compatibility issues. I tried installing using an .iso of Ubuntu 11.04 on a burned CD but the screens stops after flashing Ubuntu 11.04. Please help.

Comment: [MD5 test](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the ISO image and [check the burned CD/DVD or written USB flash drive for defects](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html). Besides that, [the question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) @JacobJohanEdwards posted a link to should provide the necessary information. If you read and follow everything there and still have problems, please edit this question to provide more details, and also post a comment here (as this may be closed as a duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this one. If you have a graphics card installed on your system then you will need to remove it completely and run the installation without the Graphics Card in there. Then you can put it back in after the installation. It is important to note that if you used WUBI to install your 12.04 then you shouldn't do a revert to 11.04 without first making a partition with your existing memory. Installing 11.04 alongside 12.04 and then  use a partition manager to format the 12.04 partition. After that then you can use that partition manager to expand the volume on the 11.04 partition. I suggest that you use a boot able USB also as it seems to function better than a CD. Again the Graphics Card is likely the best route as it happened to me like that. It can't hurt anything so try it.