# I have the 0.19.0 okular version, but it still doesn't let me save annotations in a pdf

Tags: pdf, okular, annotation

I have trouble saving annotations and highlighting I made in okular as a pdf.
I have the latest okular version:

```
Qt: 4.8.2
KDE: 4.13.0
Okular: 0.19.0
```

and use ubuntu 12.04 (precise).

I've tried the first two solutions of this thread: [How to Install Okular 0.15 on 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172126/how-to-install-okular-0-15-on-12-04-lts/) but they haven't worked for me.

I think the problem is (as mentioned in other threads) is the libpoppler package. When I use

```
sudo apt-cache okular
```

it says

```
...depends: ....libpoppler-qt4-3 (>= 0.18)....
```

I know by now that I need okular to use the 0.20 version of libpoppler, but I don't know how to force it to use it. As mentioned, I've tried the solution in the other thread.

**EDIT:**

```
:~$ apt-cache policy libpoppler-qt4-3
libpoppler-qt4-3:
Installiert: 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1
Kandidat:    0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1
Versionstabelle:
*** 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 0.18.4-1ubuntu2 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

**EDIT**

after adding the PPA with

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kalakris/okular
```

and updating my system with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**EDIT**

I get the ouput

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
OK   http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
OK   http://dl.google.com stable Release                                       
OK   http://repository.spotify.com stable Release.gpg                          
Hole:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]         
OK   http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                           
OK   http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                          
OK   http://repository.spotify.com stable Release                              
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                              
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                              
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                              
OK   http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                            
OK   http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages              
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hole:2 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49,6 kB]           
OK   http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages               
Hole:3 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [72 B]                     
OK   http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                              
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                  
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                  
OK   http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                  
OK   http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages               
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free TranslationIndex             
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                  
OK   http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                             
OK   http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                             
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                      
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                             
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                      
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hole:4 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [2.494 B]
OK   http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                      
OK   http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                       
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                  
Hole:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [104 kB]       
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                             
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                              
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                      
OK   http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                      
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                   
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                         
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                   
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                     
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                  
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages              
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                   
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages             
Hole:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1.794 B]
Hole:7 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [30,9 kB]  
Hole:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [385 kB]
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages               
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages             
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex          
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex          
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-de_DE                         
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                 
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources           
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-de                            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages          
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages    
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages    
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages           
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages     
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages       
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages     
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex        
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex  
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex  
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex    
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-de                  
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-de_DE            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                  
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-de            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-de            
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en            
Hole:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4.627   B]
Hole:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [93,1 kB]
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-de               
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-de              
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en              
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-de          
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en          
Hole:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2.453 B]
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en               
Hole:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [414 kB]
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-de    
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en    
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-de    
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en    
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-de      
OK   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-de_DE             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-de_DE                    
Hole:13 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4.620 B]
Hole:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [97,6 kB]
Hole:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2.636 B]
OK   http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex         
OK   http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex   
OK   http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex   
OK   http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de_DE                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-de                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-de                       
OK   http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en           
OK   http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en     
OK   http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de_DE                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de_DE                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
OK   http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Es wurden 1.194 kB in 2 s geholt (459 kB/s)
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
libxml2 libxml2:i386 libxml2-utils python-libxml2
4 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen 1.561 kB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt. 
Möchten Sie fortfahren [J/n]? J
Hole:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libxml2 i386 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7 [662 kB]
Hole:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libxml2 amd64 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7 [673 kB]
Hole:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libxml2-utils amd64 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7 [39,9 kB]
Hole:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python-libxml2    64 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7 [186 kB]
Es wurden 1.561 kB in 3 s geholt (469 kB/s)
(Lese Datenbank ... 1113479 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Ersetzen von libxml2:i386 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6 (durch   ./libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7_i386.deb) ...
libxml2 wird de-konfiguriert ...
Ersatz für libxml2:i386 wird entpackt ...
Vorbereitung zum Ersetzen von libxml2 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6 (durch .../libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb) ...
Ersatz für libxml2 wird entpackt ...
libxml2:i386 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7) wird eingerichtet ...
libxml2 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für libc-bin werden verarbeitet ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
(Lese Datenbank ... 1113479 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Ersetzen von libxml2-utils 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6 (durch .../libxml2-utils_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb) ...
Ersatz für libxml2-utils wird entpackt ...
Vorbereitung zum Ersetzen von python-libxml2 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6 (durch .../python-libxml2_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb) ...
Ersatz für python-libxml2 wird entpackt ...
Trigger für man-db werden verarbeitet ...
libxml2-utils (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7) wird eingerichtet ...
python-libxml2 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.7) wird eingerichtet ...
```

Sorry for the mass of information, feel free to edit away everything unnecessary (I'm not sure what is important here)

Using

```
apt-cache policy libpoppler-qt4-3
```

I get the output

```
:~$ apt-cache policy libpoppler-qt4-3
libpoppler-qt4-3:
Installiert: 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1
Kandidat:    0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1
Versionstabelle:
*** 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 0.18.4-1ubuntu2 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

hence, the same as before.

and it still doesn't work. (When I try "save as", I get an error message, when I "save a copy", the annotations are not saved.)

I'd appreciate any help,
thanks,
Hannah

Comment: What's the output for `apt-cache policy libpoppler-qt4-3` on your system? Just to be sure: Have you tried [Kalakris' PPA](http://askubuntu.com/a/280227/81372) out?

Comment: I put the output for that in the original post. Yes, I tried that approach.

Comment: OK, thanks for posting the output. You were right, the libpoppler version is the issue. You currently have 0.18.4 installed but you need 0.20+ for the editing functions (as you said yourself). The only safe way to go about this - without upgrading the whole system - is to add a PPA with a backported package of poppler. Theoretically Kalakris PPA should work and I am not quite sure what went wrong. Would you care to try the solution out again? Try adding the PPA with `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kalakris/okular` and updating your system with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Then see if PDF editing works. If not, please edit your question with the output of `apt-cache policy libpoppler-qt4-3` after the update. We can then try to find another solution.

Comment: I've done that (see original post).

Comment: Mmh, I don't understand why poppler isn't getting updated. Would you mind editing your question with the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: I added the output I got earlier when I used `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Alright, the output tells me that no package is being held back. No idea why poppler isn't getting updated. I am afraid I am out of suggestions here. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/461356/81372) will probably work but it's very dangerous and one simple mistake could leave your system unusable. You could wait for soemone else to come along or try asking [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) if anyone knows how to solve this. Sorry :/.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I'd rather not do the last one, I found a program that runs smoothly with Wine, so it's not urgent anymore and I'm nor very experienced with that kind of stuff. I'd still prefer using okular, so in case someone has another suggestion, I'd be happy to try it out.