# Okular: Your annotations will not be exported

Tags: kde, pdf, okular

I'm running `Okular 0.20.2` on Ubuntu 12.04, I made some annotations to a PDF file and when I try to save a copy of it with `Save as` (to preserve the annotations), I get the message:

```
Your annotations will not be exported.
You can export the annotated document using File -> Export As -> Document Archive
```

I'm not sure why this happens since Okular should be able to save annotations [since version 0.15](https://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html).

That same page says something about how `Okular` should have been built using `Poppler` version 0.20 or later, but I'm not sure how to check this.

Comment: As for your last remark: do `apt-cache showpkg okular` and take a look at the Dependencies section.

Comment: Similar to question number 465903: try to find which version of libpoppler you have (I have 0.31 and it works). The mentioned answers provides some help.

Comment: Sadly the comments in that question end up nowhere.

Comment: @Gabriel You can check your poppler version with `apt-cache policy libpoppler*`. As explained in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172126/how-to-install-okular-0-15-on-12-04-lts) you will need liboppler 0.20+ and an Okular release built against it to annotate PDF files directly.