# Uninstalling 12.04 to install 10.04

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I would like to uninstall 12.04 on my Asus Netbook so that I can install 10.04 which I prefer. What is the procedure for the uninstall. Tks.

Comment: What's wrong with usual approach - backup and clean install on top of 12.04?

Comment: When I try that it just checks the install CD for differences with 12.04 and doesn't start the usual install sequence for the 10.04 ie nothing to click on

Answer (score 0):

Make an install CD for 10.04. Backup your data. Install 10.04 -- the installer will prompt you for how you want the hard drive to be partitioned, choose to use all the space, deleting the previous OS.