# How can I downgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I have recently updated my Ubuntu install from 10.04 to 12.04, However 10.04 is much faster how can I retrieve 10.04 without losing all my data ie: bookmarks and emails and downloads. Help would be much appreciated.