# Undo repository upgrade

Tags: repository, software-sources

I recently added

> deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main

to my sources.list and did an upgrade. This has screwed a few things up and I would like to revert back to my previous package versions. Is there a way to do this with ppa-purge?

Comment: Why don't you remove it from your sources.list?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, looks like you've inadvertently started a partial operating system upgrade! Your best bet is to probably just upgrade to 12.10!

- [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: technically, it is possible to undo that (I have done so before, using a perl script provided by a community wiki page), but it really breaks the system