# how to downgrade from 13.04 to 12.10

Tags: downgrade, shared-folders, shared-library, 13.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I am new to Ubuntu and had a update pop up and said yes without looking at it and now I am at 13.04. I don't have any problems but I do have an issue of not being able to connect to my windows machines any longer.  I ether need to know how to downgrade without losing my data or a simple way to share files again with my other machines.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not simple downgrade path supported.  You can try installing again and when it asks how you want to install specify "Do Something Else" and it will take you to the advanced partitioner.  There, you should specify the partitions to use but **do not** click the box to format the /home partition if you have a separate one, or the / (root) partition if it also contains your /home.

The Ubiquity installer will then install over the top of the existing files leaving everything else in place.  Because downgrading is not supported however, I'm not sure if this cause further breakage.

Regardless, I recommend that you back up all of your important data before you proceed any further.  Development releases can and do get broken by an update at any time during the development cycle.

After you get it back up and running, make sure that you don't have update manager set to check for development releases.  I'd even recommend that you set it to **not** tell you about stable releases either.  They come out every six months - you can upgrade at any time if you really want to.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for answering this is what I have read all around the internet when looking for an answer, I also figured out my file sharing issue it was simple and I just was over thinking my problem so I am just going to stick with this and I made update manager to not tell me about anything but security updates.

Comment: That's probably safest for now, however at some point you are going to have to finish the updates to 13.04 when it is released otherwise you will be stuck at 13.04 Pre-Alpha 1 (There's still two alpha releases, two beta releases and a release candidate to go before final release.  You really did get in early didn't you?  I recommend that you wait until the end of May next year before you try updating it again, However expect that even the security releases may break somthing between now and then.