# Python-Speechd?

Tags: 12.10, python, python-2.7, orca, text-to-speech

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10, am fooling around with some Python code. In earlier releases, I used to be able to do:

```
import speechd
```

And now I get that the module does not exist. It also tells my the following when I try to install python-speechd:

```
Package python-speechd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsolete, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-speechd' has no installation candidate.
```

What should I do? I'd like to keep using speech-dispatcher if I can. https://live.gnome.org/Orca/SpeechDispatcher says that I should try to install python-speechd, which doesn't work. Thank you in advance - I searched everywhere but I couldn't find anything.

**EDIT:**
I did a little digging, and this seems to be an issue with Python 2.7, since python3-speechd is installed but not python-speechd. **The following works:**

```
python3 -c "import speechd"
```

**but this does NOT (can't find module speechd):**

```
python2.7 -c "import speechd"
```

It would be great to get this working with Python 2.7.

**SECOND EDIT:**
I tried installing python-speechd from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/i386/python-speechd/0.7.1-6ubuntu3
But it said that it's installation conflicted with python3-speechd.

Comment: You might actually consider filing a bug report for this on launchpad. It seems like a packaging flaw.

Answer (score 4):

As part of the migration of both [Orca](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/orca-list/2012-June/msg00335.html) and [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3) to Python 3, the Python Speech Dispatcher bindings have [been migrated to Python 3](https://its.freebsoft.org/its/issues/14556) and no longer support Python 2. Technically, it would be easy for those bindings to support Python 2 and to package Python 2 bindings, but it has not been done.

What can you do about it?

- I suggest that you use Python 3, which is the way forward and the only way to be able to continue using speechd from Python in the future.
- You can try to install [Speech Dispatcher 0.7.1](http://devel.freebsoft.org/pub/projects/speechd/speech-dispatcher-0.7.1.tar.gz) manually: it's the last version with the Python 2 bindings. See the [INSTALL](http://git.freebsoft.org/?p=speechd.git;a=blob;f=INSTALL;h=22a874c26e0e4e4a86dadb238d5685769f21ecdf;hb=e5f55283a6b161ef2bc45d9373c0dee0d266a210) file.
- Another solution is to downgrade Ubuntu to 12.04, which is a bad idea but can be done with some fighting: see this [Ask Ubuntu question on downgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version).