# Why no "import speechd" in Python 3?

Tags: python

Despite a page (link below) implying that speechd works with Python 3, "import speechd" from within Python 3.4.2 gets "no module named 'speechd'". (While I have reasons to prefer Python 2.7, the linked page suggests that's not possible.)

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04: Synaptic shows python3-speechd as being installed.

[Python-Speechd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224803/python-speechd)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing IDLE 3 ( `sudo apt-get install idle3` ). Open IDLE 3 and type `import speechd` and it should work. Does it work? Type `help('speechd')` to show speechd help.

Comment: This worked for me in 3.4.0.