# Can I downgrade 12.10 back to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I have had nothing but problems with my box since I upgraded to 12.10.
I'd like to go back to 12.04 (I had no problems at all) - is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can in effect install previous versions of all your packages, as were present in 12.04.

But, I am not sure if downgrading as such is possible.

Your best bet would be to do a complete reinstall.