# Downgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Recently I selected to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04LTS to Ubuntu12.10. There are some issues in this version  because of which the CPU is getting heated up (Intel Core i3). I would like to know if there are some known problems in the release that can be rectified or is there a way to downgrade the Ubuntu release ?

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling is easiest, but you can follow these instructions to edit the packages files and downgrade the kernel that has the changes you don't want.  [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: I ended up installing "Jupiter Applet" and reducing the performance of CPU to power-saving mode. Seems like overheating is a known bug in 12.10 that is being looked after.