# How to downgrade Ubuntu after 12.10 issues?

Tags: installation, uninstall, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I installed 12.10 removing Windows XP on a Netbook. The installation was successfully but the system is working too slow.

I have tried to reformat the drives so I can **downgrade** but none of the reinstalls (12.04 & 11.10) worked.

All I want to do is start again, clean the whole hard drive so there is no trace of 12.10 to enable a fresh install of 11.10 (I believe this works fine with my netbook specs) or even Windows XP.

I don't know where to start!

Answer (score 3):

just make a bootable usb and install 11.10 you don't have to do anything more.

actually make a bootable usb for 12.04 and then boot with the live-cd. and choose the install option where you "install and use the whole hdd", so that you get a fresh start. 11.10 will only be supported until April 2013, therefor I suggest to install 12.04 because it's the current LTS.

Yes You can install windows but you must reinstall grub afterwards.

Comment: Till now - haven't been able to install 11.10. Only 12.10 - even booting from USB. However, have just managed to reformat the hard-drove via "Gparted" - still couldn;t get 11.10 to run, but looks like 12.04 is now installing.

I do still have a boot issue with 12.04 regarding Lightdm which I can only get around at the moment with "sudo service lightdm restart".

Once 12.04 is installed - presume I will be able to re-install windows XP if I wanted to without too much issue?

Comment: @user116863 updated my question.