# Will I lose Unity-2d if I upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, unity-2d, partial-upgrade

I want to continue to use Unity-2d which I have setup on my 12.04 install...but some of the new 12.10 features I would like to use.

- new Disk utility with auto mount settings built in
- easier printer setup
- unity webapps
- and more new updates

will i lose unity 2d when I run the upgrade (from update manager)

Answer (score 3):

If you run the upgrade, you will lose the option called "Unity 2D." Ubuntu made some architectural changes from 12.04 to 12.10, one of which was consolidating the two versions of Unity into one codebase. The new "Unity" option can automatically switch to CPU operation when it detects that your graphics hardware is insufficient.

Phoronix wrote [an article confirming the changes](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE2MTQ), and their article notes that the new version of CPU-operated Unity will run best on 64-bit machines.

You might want to try a LiveCD version of 12.10 to see how Unity behaves before you run the upgrade, because once you do upgrade there is [no easy way to downgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) again.

Comment: I have had this machine on 12.10 but just about every 2 minutes I get a "something has crashed".

also unity is noticably slower. is there a way to say...hay my graphics card MAY be ABLE to but I want less?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ubuntu 12.10 is to taxing for some older hardware. This is the way of the world, but Canonical has tried to make Unity work with both older and new hardware. If you can use Unity-2D, you should simply be able to upgrade and not notice much of a slowdown.

If this slowdown is too much, perhaps you could use a different desktop environment? There are quite a few nice, lightweight ones that work great on hardware that can't run unity. I'd recommend E17, KDE, MATE or Cinnamon.

Or, if you want to really speed up your system, you could even try another linux distro.

Comment: so ... if I am _currently_ running U2d, and then upgrade...will I loose U2d.
or does unity merge unity2d? im still confused