# How to uninstall ubuntu 12.10 and install 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I have a macbook pro and i have successfully installed windows 7 via bootcamp and then installed ubuntu 12.10 along side windows 7. It works fine... but for my school project i need to use ubuntu 12.04 - i know i should have known this from the start, would have made things easier :-/

Now my question is how to uninstall 12.10 and then reinstall 12.04? i think it wouldnt be a problem to install 12.04 but the question is more how to uninstall 12.10?

thank you.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/49869/114818

Comment: Use WUBI to install Ubuntu 12.04 inside Windows 7. That way you wont need to uninstall anything.

Comment: @CuriousApprentice Why? Similarly, it's possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside *both* Windows and Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score -1):

Boot into windows 7 then go to control panel add/remove program and then check for ubuntu in the list if it is listed then do remove from it.
The simplest procedure would be to boot with the Live CD for 12.04LTS.

Install it on the current / partition by formatting it during installation. Select other partitions like home, swap etc. if applicable but do not format them.

When you reboot, Grub menu should indicate Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The removal part of this answer is a Wubi-specific solution, and the OP said they installed Ubuntu "along side" Windows (not "inside" it). So this doesn't apply to the OP's situation.