# Upgrade to 12.04 did not seem to work, can I restore back to 10.04 as I was, am stuck at grub prompt?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, rescue-mode

Is it possible to restore my dual boot PC to 10.04 LTS?  I am concerned about rescuing my data if the upgrade to 12.04 has not worked.  What options do I have from the grub prompt?

Comment: This question is going to be closed as a duplicate.  If you think this is not a duplicate please edit your question to include why and flag this for re-opening.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put a livecd or live usb into the computer, and boot from it. This way you can access your files, and save them to somewhere else.

You cannot restore the 10.04 ubuntu. The only way is to reinstall.

Comment: As the [this duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) says, Ubuntu can be migrated, but it's quite hard.