# how to uninstall Ubuntu 12.10 to install Ubuntu 12.04 with only Ubuntu 12.10 with usb pen drive (Startup Disk Creator doesn't finish the creation)

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, live-usb

due to my ignorance and the need to use a programm I can't install on Ubuntu 12.10, I decided to uninstall it to install Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit, because I have a 64 bit laptop). I have only Ubuntu 12.10 as OS and no idea of the procedure (I can't find it in this forum or on the site, there are only instructions useful if you have also Windows or other softwar running with Ubuntu, which I have not.)  I can't even download Ubuntu 12.04 on my usb pen drive, because it stops at some point. It says that usb-creator-gtk crashes with SIGSEGV at the executable path /usr/bins/usb-creator-gtk. Any Idea? Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to revert to an older version of Ubuntu once a newer version is installed, so if you want to go from 12.10 to 12.04, you will have to download and install 12.04 or earlier. As to why you are unable to download it, that should probably be another thread.
Edit: More details on downgrading: [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: Thanks data88, Do you think that as an alternative I could make a new partition and install Ubuntu 12.04 there? (given that I find an other way to download it)

Comment: You could install it in a partition, but if you are able to download 12.04 from another computer and make a bootable USB, that is probably the easiest route.

Comment: Thanks again!! I just did it (I created the bootable usb from the pc I have at home, an old slow windows) ^_^ How can I make a partition? I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on FreeDOS (new laptop) few days ago and I didn't specified anything about partition.

Comment: ps: I have a Samsung NP300E5X-A04IT and it seems that there's a bug in it. You can't install in UEFI mode in the BIOS, instead it's necessary to do it in CSM mode https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1040557 Do you know can I disable UEFI in BIOS? I know that these are a lot of questions and you aswered already very gently to my previuos requests of help, so if you can't answer this time thanks anyway!

Comment: I checked, the terminal says that I haven't any valid table of partitions.  (marta@marta-300E4C-300E5C-300E7C:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes

Comment: Dispositivo Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 2048 499711 248832 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 501758 976771071 488134657 5 Esteso
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5 501760 976771071 488134656 8e Linux LVM

Comment: (my translation):the disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid table of partitions
the disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid table of partitions

Comment: well, I installed Gparted to understand better the situation, unfortunately the improvement isn't extraordinary (^_^; ) It seems to me that I should rescue the original four parts partition. Gparted gives me this link http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download but I haven't understood which version is better for 12.10. ^_^;