# how can i go back to 12.04 from 12.10 in a dual boot pc?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, downgrade

I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and I have a lot of issues i.e. mouse doesn't respond . Is there a way to go back to previous state with the 12.04 DVD or I have to erase everything and re-install?

Comment: Erase and re-install will be easiest but take a look here [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](http://askubuntu.com/q/49869/107450)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good guide on how to downgrade an Ubuntu installation which you can find here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto

However, it is a better idea to do a reinstall. Back up any data you can (this is why it's a good idea to separate root and /home) and reinstall... you'll probably save more time in the long run unless you have critical data.

Comment: Thanked for all the help and really fast respond. I erased and reinstall them and everything is back to normal.