# Can I install an older version of ubuntu over a new one?

Tags: 12.04, installation, downgrade

I installed ubuntu 12.04 lts on my old cpu and it just dosen't run right (lags, and other bugs)So I'm wondering if installing an old version of ubuntu on a cpu with a newer version is possible?

Like ubuntu 12.04 to 10.04. I already have the .iso file of 10.04 and I'm about to burn it into an installer dvd.

Again, I'm wondering if installing an old version over a new one is possible as I would want to replace 12.04 with 10.04

Comment: If you want to overwrite your actual Ubuntu version with another one then "yes" you can. Otherwise if you want to downgrade, I would say that if possible, it could be a little bit hard. Please edit your question to include your CPU's specs.

Comment: I would suggest using Lubuntu if your CPU is that old.  Not that it helps, of course, but you might want to consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont Think you Can.

If you just want to Have it downgraded with your documents just make a backup and then Install the Older One (Format The Existing Ubuntu Partition Or Just Press Erase and Reinstall Ubuntu(Version)

Here is a quick Guide on how to backup your files 
http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/

Enjoy and If i answered Your Question Press Answered :P

Answer (score 0):

You can, similar questions: see [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version). If you don't want to redownload, you can mention your CD as source in Ubuntu repositories. 
In Synaptic: settings|repositories|other sources, 
in Ubuntu software center: Edit|software sources|other software.