# Non LTS to LTS? Possible?

Tags: downgrade

Is it at all possible to move from an non-LTS distro to an LTS one, IE 13.04 to 12.04 LTS? If so, how would it be done?

Comment: It is not really possible to Downgrade Ubuntu safely and get to a stable state. I would suggest waiting till the next LTS, or re-installing Ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to downgrade 13.04 to 12.04 by editing the packaging files like sources.lst and /etc/apt/preferences , you may get errors as you go.

The best thing is to re-install using a live CD or bootable iso of ubuntu 12.04.2.