# Ubuntu 12.04 is very slow in my Lenovo

Tags: installation, upgrade

I had been using Ubuntu 10 in my Lenovo 3000 N100. When i upgraded to 12.04 it is very slow. How can I fix it. My friend told me my lap does not have sufficient configuration to support Ubuntu 12.04. Can i switch back to earlier versions. Please suggest me the best for my Lenovo 3000 N100

Comment: Sorry, but there is no Ubuntu 12.4. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Twinsen The user will be meaning 12.04

Comment: @Twinsen most users make such errors.  When they say "12.4" you can substitute "12.04" without calling them out on such minor mistakes.  I'll revise the message accordingly.

Comment: I would suggest you try using Lubuntu 12.04 as it's very lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never upgraded the standard 512MB memory, chances are thats where the problem is. (can you please check your hardware specs and edit your post?).
If that is indeed your problem, you can do one of three things:

- Downgrade back to 10.
  You can read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) that that is possible but not recomended. But if you really want to go back to your previous version, its better to backup your /home dir and reinstall that version. But as 10.04 is not being supported anymore, you should think about that.
- increase your memory (your lenovo can go up to 2G, which should be enough)
- You can switch to a up-to-date  but 'light' version of Ubuntu like Xubuntu or Lubuntu