# Ubuntu 13.10 upgraded from 13.04 issues

Tags: 13.04, graphics, keyboard, 13.10, downgrade

The keyboard stopped working after a while, I started using 13.04 again VIA USB because I am waiting for the keyboard issues that 13.10 has to get an update. 13.04 had tons of issues I didn't care about because most of it worked. Now almost none of it works. There's even a huge amount of graphical errors. Others have had these issues I've noticed while looking at the similar questions area next to this text box, but my question is can I downgrade 13.10 to 13.04?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10, but its working like heaven. U try reinstalling it or download the image from official ubuntu and make clean install. But before making clean install, backup your data.

Comment: I found out that the issue with the keyboard is enabling the on-screen keyboard through the universal access settings. What sucks is I still now and then get the error on the graphics. The the screen goes black (not like in terminal form) after it loads for 1 second when booting but is still on, and then mouse pointer disappears and it goes black when logging in until I move it or wait for the system to boot up fully after I log on which I assume is the reason I keep getting the graphic error message after I log on.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Falling back to Gnome Flashback (no effects) works well for me. But I miss the Unity desktop. Let me know if you ever find out a solution.