# how to downgrade whole system

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, package-management, do-release-upgrade

I have broken and partial upgraded system, it was attempted to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 some how things did not went fine, and in next consecutive months I kept using this system. 
Later on when ever I needed to install a package like bind9 or some thing or some package I always landed in trouble,either I select one by one which package or dependency needed to be downgraded or I do some kind of circus.It wasted a lot of precious time.

Is it possible to bring back the system from this state to a state when 12.04 fresh installation package were present.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Comment: its possible upto some extent , but a fresh new installation will be far better then this.

Answer (score 4):

Not reliably, *whether the upgrade was successful or not*. Attempting to do so would take an awful lot of time and cross-checking. I strongly suggest backing up everything in and under /home then do a wipe-and-reinstall, as the quickest and most reliable path back to the stable system you prize.

Comment: Is it possible when the upgrade was successful?

Comment: Also, compiling a list of packages you have installed and want (e.g. LibreOffice packages), as well as any PPAs you have, will make it easier for you to get back a similar setup you had after wiping and reinstalling.