# How can I remove YUMI (multiboot usb creator) software?

Tags: uninstall, deb, yumi

I downloaded the **.deb version** of  **YUMI (multiboot usb creator**) from the [pendrive homepage](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and I wanted to make a bootable usb for Windows 98 to run on Virtualbox, but anyway the software asked for my sudo password inside the software itself and I felt it was a fishing scam, so **I wanted to remove it**.

But when I go to the **Ubuntu Software Center** it says "reinstall", there is **no remove option**. And I wasn't able to remove it from the **terminal** using `apt-get --purge remove yumi_0.0.1-1_all.deb`

I am running Xubuntu 14.04.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to use sudo and enter your password to install or uninstall applications or make changes to the system.

Comment: fyi, YUMI is perfectly safe. It needs sudo permissions to create the bootloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typed it incorrectly, open the terminal and type this command instead:

```
sudo apt-get purge yumi
```

Enter your password (as you have to do so each and every time you use sudo) and follow the prompts. This will completely remove and uninstall the application and all of the files associated with it as well (purge).

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the yumi .deb file from the webpage? It should show up in  `synaptic` (or even `apt`), search for it and remove it. I'm not exactly sure what name it will be under, I think it'd be just "yumi". If not in Synaptic try `apt-cache search yumi`?

Purge is not an option of `apt-get`, just using `remove` or `purge` alone should work... but probably not with the ".deb" part of the filename, use the name you get from searching above, or just remove in Synaptic.

Or you might be able to check your log files & see what it's called (if it was installed recently), in `/var/log/dpkg.log` or maybe `/var/log/apt/...`

PS. yumi probably can't access your devices to create a bootable USB without running as root, so requires your sudo password, probably not unusual. Browse through the [source code](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/ubuntu/yumi_0.0.1.orig.tar.gz) if you'd like to be sure (link was on the page you provided).

But you're already running linux, so just follow these directions yourself:

- See https://askubuntu.com/a/554834/129271

  Cliff Notes:

  1. Mount the usb
  2. Install grub `grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/sdx` (replacing x with your actual USB device & /mnt/usb with mounted dir)
  3. Put demo grub.cfg ( http://pendrivelinux.com/downloads/multibootlinux/grub.cfg ) in `/mnt/USB/boot/grub` and edit to match your iso's
- Main page directions: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/

Comment: another one that only lists installed apps is `dpkg -l | grep yumi` ; nice cliff notes