# How to downgrade gnome 3.14 to 3.12 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, gnome

After upgrading gnome from 3.12 to 3.14 some icons are looking larger and weird in unity.
Icons for Chrome, System Settings Dialog box as not properly getting displayed. How to solve? Should I need to apply any patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used [this method](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-install-gnome-314-in-ubuntu.html) of installing Gnome 3.14 *(basically using the `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging` and/or `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` PPAs - the article also details some problems that occur in Unity caused by installing 3.14)*, you should be able to use the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

This disables the PPAs and any reverts to the official repositories' packages, downgrading Gnome 3.14 back to the default installed version. This should restore the bugs of large icons, Ambiance theme problems, client-side decorations etc if you want to use Unity not Gnome 3.14.

Comment: Yeah, I have used the way you mentioned for installation of Gnome.

Comment: Is it possible to downgrade OS version also? from Ubuntu 14.10 to 14.04 LTS as 14.10 is unstable and many issues with graphics and all.

Comment: Try this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version