# XFCE - Unknown Tray Icon

Tags: apt, xubuntu, icons, xfce

Question:

After doing an update on my Xubuntu:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

I found after restarting the following tray icon I was not able to identify:

[image: A black monitor (screen) with a red "do not park here" sign.]

I was guessing that it has something to do with the graphic driver, but I am using a Lenovo T61 from 10 years ago and I think it has an integrated graphic chip.

System info:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Lenovo T61 (2006?)
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7100  @ 1.80GHz

I do not get any description while hovering over or clicking it. Google search brought nothing up.
The computer is working, so it is not a big deal but I am curious what he wants to tell me :D

I appreciate your suggestions!

Best regards

Carlo

Comment: This happened to me EXACTLY the same! I attached a screenshot and awaiting review.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it is way easier to understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

The icon means that you have broken packages.  To fix that, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or you can install synaptic using

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed, open the program, and click on Edit --> Fix Broken Packages.

[image]

Comment: I actually tried your suggestions, but I think I have to use "sudo apt-get install --fix-broken" or "sudo apt-get remove --fix-broken" because otherwise my command is not accepted. It did not alter anything on my system and stated: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. -> also after installing synaptic as you described, it just states that there are no dependency problems.

Comment: I just fixed the command.  Try it now.

Comment: I already tried it with the fix: sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Did not see broken packages in aptitude either.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this: sudo apt-get -f install libhwloc-plugins -> It was a package which did not update yesterday and I was wondering why so I just did it manually like this and the update worked after that.

Comment: I don't have them installed at all.

Comment: Is there a way to roll back an update?

Comment: @jdsika: If you now what has been update, you might.

Comment: You actually can rollback with synaptic, but the following thread describes the problem with it :D http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version