# How to downgrade from ubuntu 15 to ubuntu 14 to escape systemd?

Tags: downgrade, systemd

Is it possible to downgrade from ubuntu 15 to ubuntu 14?

We would like to stay on 14 until we have decided on a distro to replace ubuntu that does not use systemd.

How is that done?

Comment: This won't be a hard choice, as there are very few distros not using systemd.

Comment: Read " Permanent switch back to upstart"https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: You can switch 15.04 to init.d from the grub menu. Why not do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a risky thing to try a rollback, there's no easy way to downgrade.

Best option: After backing up your stuff, re-install the OS.

As user1362567 said on another question

"

First generate a list of what you have installed on your system. You can do this by typing the following in the terminal.

> sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep '[[:space:]]install$' | \awk '{print
>   $1}' > package_list

copy your /home and /etc folder to a backup media.

Re-install the desired ubuntu version [Mentioned in the original thread : 10.04], and then run this command to install what you had before.

> cat package_list | xargs sudo apt-get install

Note that you might have to do some cleaning of the /etc and /home folder for incompatible settings.
"
I have to thank user1362567 for explaining it well.  Link to the original post : [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version/3670#3670)

Comment: Thank You very much. I upgraded and tried to learn to live with it instead.
After all - it can't be that bad when som many use it. It turned out that my problem was the speed in which the machine started. 
I fixed that with a wait. Not pretty, but it'll have to do.