# Can I downgrade the kernel on Ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, downgrade

I have an application that works fine on **14.04.1** but does not work fine on **14.04.2**.

I found a bug report that indicates the newer kernel in **14.04.2** is the source of this issue.  Is possible to downgrade the kernel in **14.04.2** from  **3.16.0-39** to **3.13.0-43**, which was the kernel used in **14.04.1**?  Or, do I have to remove **14.04.2** and reinstall **14.04.1**?

Comment: read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Comment: I doubt that a user space application can have this kind of issues. What is that application?

Comment: Here is were I found the discussion on switch back to the original kernel https://forums.sonarr.tv/t/native-mono-crashes/4985

Comment: It seems that will not solve your issue. In 3.13 kernels there is same problem. And you can't just downgrade to 3.13.0-46, if it was not installed. Just wait till it is fixed, or install 4.0.

Comment: And it looks like it is being fixed already. Maybe already fixed. What is your current kernel version?

Comment: I currently have 3.16.0-39

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can switch to 3.13 kernel easily.

1. Install 3.13 kernel by running

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic
   ```
2. Remove all `linux-headers` and `linux-image` packages of 3.19 version using synaptic. This will also remove 3.19 meta packages.

Comment: notice that 14.04.2 comes with linux-generic-lts-utopic which is 3.16.x.x and linux-generic-lts-vivid is 3.19.x.x which can be manually installed ;)

Comment: I know that. That's why I gave that command.

Comment: I just meant you mentioned to remove 3.19 version packages in your answer ;)

Comment: And this will remove "lts-utopic" too.

Comment: yes if they are installed... I mean 3.19 ;)