# Downgrade Ubuntu Vivid to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, downgrade

I am now running Ubuntu 15.04 latest version on my Dell laptop(Inspiron 15R).

I find this version almost unstable, and not really good for my work. I want to downgrade this version to 14.04.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, albeit with a *lot* of work - so is not really worth it.

Your best bet is to install 14.04 from scratch - ie. a fresh install.

However, if you really want to do a downgrade, take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version/49872#49872) answer.

Comment: Thank you, but for a fresh install I'd loose all the installed packages and data ?

Comment: @tonytom Yes unfortunately - so you'll need to do a backup before installation.