# downgrading the Ubuntu 14.10 to 14.04

Tags: updates

Why don't you have downgrade tool?? I know it's a challenge but that's what LINUX is to accept the challenge. See I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 and I am very happy from it but I am not getting any software updates because its not LTS. So now I want to downgrade it, because I want my softwares up to date and security too. Now to go back to 14.04 LTS, I have to install again with cd or USB stick, it's tedious job. So u can make a downgrade tool.

Comment: As a developer, sometimes it's just not possible to take a step back without creating a whole new crock of issues which leave leave you wishing you'd left things as they were. Sorry, but you need to bite the bullet and persevere with the consequences of wishing to be at the 'bleeding edge' or reinstall the earlier version having profited from your experience.

Comment: It is not impossible, but you have to do it manually. See [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto

Answer (score 0):

In the most cases, you would have a broken system. Start a upgrade to 15.04 to get security updates and wait for the next LTS release (16.04).

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

After that, change the update behavior to LTS.

> Check the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`. `Prompt=normal` offers upgrades from any release to a newer release; `Prompt=never` never offers release upgrades; `Prompt=lts` only offers upgrades from LTS to LTS. You need root privileges to edit this file.

<sub>[partially taken from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades)</sub>

---

But I have an idea. You're right, that's Linux and you can do what you want. You could create a downgrade tool. **;)**