# Can I upgrade from Kubuntu 14.10 but stay on KDE 4?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, kde

I'm running Kubuntu 14.10 on an older Toshiba Satellite. I would rather stay with KDE 4 and not move up to KDE 5. Is there any way to upgrade my Kubuntu release to 15.04 and/or 15.10 while staying on KDE 4 or is that just asking for problems down the road?

My main reason is that I didn't realize 14.10 would be unsupported as of this past June and I mistakenly upgraded from the LTS 14.04. I don't believe there is a downgrade path so the only way is up. Now I can't get any updates.

Comment: The only way would be if you compile all of KDE for yourself ;)

Comment: You could always do a fresh install of the LTS version again.

Comment: Or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)...