# Fixing/rolling back broken installation

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, nvidia, upgrade, 15.04

I recently broke my dual boot installation (Windows & and Ubuntu) during an upgrade -- supposedly to fix missing dependencies but unwittingly upgraded from trusty to vivid, and now vivid won't boot up to the UI, obviously due to driver issues and now I've got a black screen.

In fact, initially grub went crazy and I couldn't boot up to Windows as well until I booted up from the Ubuntu bootable USB drive the grub issue "resolved itself". But the Ubuntu installation is still booting to blackscreen. I can select the recovery mode (recovery/dpkg) option but I get the error message `upgrade from vivid to trusty is not supported`. I can also bootup Ubuntu to terminal with networking support. I've tried loads up options to bootup without the nVidia driver but **NONE** of them work.

How can I fix my installation without having to reinstall Ubuntu in a way that it messes up working applications in the previous install? I don't mind staying on vivid or rolling back to trusty as long as my installation works.

**Update**

Here's what my screen looks like when I boot up
[image]

Comment: For the downgrade, it's a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version --- for the fixing part, there is no sufficient data to understand what's happening; try http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @Rmano I've updated my question.