# Ubuntu LTS 18.04 stuck at splash screen after routine update

Tags: boot, upgrade, updates, 18.04

Apparently, its that time of the year again when an [update breaks ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725055/fixing-rolling-back-broken-installation). This year after a routine update Ubuntu 18.04 LTS gets stuck at the splash screen. (Please note that I was **not** upgrading to LTS 18.04. I did that months ago. This was a routine software update.). I've tried booting to recovery mode and was presented with a root log on which I could not use because I hadn't created a root user.

**Update**

The bootup process does eventually proceed past the splash screen after a loooooong time.

Comment: Do you use gdm? If so you have likely been bitten by the latest kernel update. Try booting into an old kernel.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052159/why-did-bionic-kernel-update-to-4-15-0-24-get-removed-from-the-repos for more info.

Comment: Erm ... so I decided to try booting up again and leaving the bootup process at the splash screen and after a fre munites I get the log on screen!!! I'll try reboiting. I hope this amount of delay is not the new normal. (Oddly there's a new update and I'm a bit scared to apply it. No kernel stuff this time tho.)

Comment: According to comments on the bug report, if you are in the 'this update caused my computer to boot really slow but not totally crash it' club, you can fix that by installing the `haveged` package.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Brilliant! Problem solved.  Please phrase your reply as an answer so that I can mark it as such.

Comment: see my answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1150970/926999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to comments on the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/linux/+bug/1779827) associated with the bad kernel update, if you are in the 'this update caused my computer to boot really slow but not totally crash it' club, you can fix that by installing the `haveged`package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help for those whom the issue occurred on Virtual box ( ubuntu as Guest ):

I went through the settings of my virtual machine and disabled 3D checkbox for the graphic controller. And my system is back to normal. It is a simple workaround in order to wait for the last update from ubuntu.
Once the issue is fixed, sudo apt-get update will fix the broken update.
Hope that helps!