# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at purple loading screen after new update

Tags: boot

Today I switched on my laptop and ubuntu 18.04 stuck on the purple loading screen after boot. As I have another ubuntu boot on my drive, I boot into it and everything was working normally.

it boots on recovery mode.

How do I solve it?

I tried:

1. [Boot into recovery mode and edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf WaylandEnable=false](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099111)

Problem keeps the same.

Ubuntu 18.04

[image]

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/613582/terminal-wont-launch-after-upgrading

Comment: @Hamad , it is stuck on boot

Comment: talk to me I think i can help you because i had the same issue and after struggling for 5 days I fixed it

Comment: @H.sanati can you please share your solution?

Comment: @Abbas i posted the answer. tell me if it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue can have two reasons:

**1- your system has Nvidia graphics card and its driver is not installed.**

for this you should follow these steps:

When you start your system you can see the grub menu that has options like `Ubuntu`, `Advanced options for Ubuntu` and ...( I have a Asus laptop that I must press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on to see the grub menu) select `Ubuntu` but **don't press <kbd>Enter</kbd>**, press <kbd>E</kbd> instead.

You will see boot parameters for Ubuntu. In this step we are going to use an open source graphics instead of Nvidia temporarily to install the right graphics driver. In the line which starts with `linux` add this at the end of the line: `nouveau.modeset=0` after `... quiet splash` like this: `quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0`

Now you can press <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting and you should see the login page and it won't be stuck. (don't do the second reasons solution if you logged in successfully. follow the final step)

**2- your display manager has a problem.**

When you upgrade to 18.04, Ubuntu uses gdm as a default display manager that has more code complexity than lightdm. so you should change it to lightdm (even if your Ubuntu uses lightdm do it anyway because maybe lightdm is broken)

Go to recovery mode and bring up the shell (with networking enabled) as root now type these commands:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Select lightdm as default display manager and reboot you should see the login page.

I recommend you to do both solutions at the same time if you are not sure which to use.

**Final Step**

Now after logging in you should install the right version of Nvidia graphics on your system.
Type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Now you can see the drivers available for you Nvidia graphic card install the recommended version like this (the version can be different on your system but mine is 390):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
```

**Warning:** don't add any PPA for Nvidia

After installation is complete reboot your system normally and it must work.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue as Steve reported in another answer. step1 in this answer made no difference, but step2 worked :)

Comment: @CorinFletcher I'm glad it worked :)

Comment: Tried the 2nd solution first and it worked like a charm.  I'd do +100 if I could.

Comment: Very useful to fix ATI X1600 problem on IMac late 2006, with Ubuntu upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. Log in screen was like broken and logging in to the desktop results in black windowed aplications (totally black), like Firefox or even the software updater. At least the terminal could be seen nicely and I could apply the second fix, going back to lightdm. Now Perfect!!! Thank you.

Comment: There is a typo in `nauveau.modeset=0`. It is spelled `nouveau.modeset=0`, right?