# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in purple screen with "Ubuntu 18.04" written

Tags: boot, 18.04, updates

I did some updates with the Ubuntu update manager and now I am stuck on the Ubuntu 18.04 purple screen with the 4 dots.  I am able to go in recovery mode.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have a Dell Latitude. The kernel versions I have available in GRUB are:

- `5.4.0-42-generic`
- `5.3.0-62-generic`

I know that there are many questions like this out there and I tried these without any luck:

1. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/792086/335044)
2. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099111/335044)
3. In the past, I used [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1146150/335044).

   - The problem continued since the package always wanted to be updated so I put it on hold with `echo "intel-microcode hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections` (from [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/335044))
4. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1150970/335044)

I am not able to understand where it gets stuck, is there any way to do that?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many different solutions tested (I was going crazy) I understood that the thing that was making my ubuntu partition stuck in the purple screen was just a USB 3.0 hard disk.

Indeed, I can reproduce the error as many times as I want and it happens consistently that when I connect the hard disk I get stuck, when it is disconnected it does not get stuck.

I hope that this will help someone else like me in this situation.