# How to replace current Ubuntu with an older version without harming the Windows partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have currently Ubuntu 15.10 installed on my system in dual-boot mode alongside Windows 10. As I need to run an older version of OpenFOAM software on my machine, I need to replace the 15.10 with 13.04 version as that(and 12.04, 12.10) are the only versions of Ubuntu supported by this older OpenFOAM version.

So, how do I go about installing Ubuntu 13.10, replacing the 15.10 while leaving the Windows partition alone? What option do I have to choose during installation from USB drive, that will do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead and start installing Ubuntu 13.04 rather than downgrading as mentioned in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version). It will be less efforts to install 13.04 and more cleaner approach. Moreover you already have the disk partitions on which you need to install Ubuntu. I would check with the release notes of that software(OpenFOAM) -in general the software/tools that i am using are all supporting LTS release(Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS). It's better to be at 14.04.3 LTS rather than 13.04