# How to cancel a release upgrade completely?

Tags: apt, upgrade, repository, do-release-upgrade, 16.04

So, the software updater comes up and says that there is a new Ubuntu version, do you want to upgrade it or not. I accidentally press yes. After that I interrupted the upgrade by closing it, and rebooting.

Now I can't download packages, because they're disabled. It says:

> Disabled on upgrade to Xenial

How can i stop that upgrade to Xenial?

This is my first question, so I apologize if it's formatted incorrectly. .

Comment: Which version were you previously on? `Trusty`?

Comment: I'm currently on Trusty. The problem is Ubuntu Updater thinks that I want to upgrade to Xenial. So it disabled all the trusty repositories in preparation to the upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you managed to get trusty to upgrade to `Xenial`, which is still not finished. Scheduled to be released on [April 21st](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule).

To revert the changes

- In the `Software & Updates` go to the tab `Other Software`
- enable all the Trusty packages,

  - or rename the `xenial` part to `trusty`.

---

To set it to a default setting do the following:

- In the dash search for `Software & Updates`
- Open `Software & Updates`
- select the `Updates` tab
- in the `Notify me of a new Ubuntu Version`, select `For long-term support versions`

This will only notify you when Xenial, the stable version, is out

> Note: None of this is recommended, and *might* break your system. **Use at your own risk**.

I'd recommended to do a full backup of everything and just do a clean install.

See the following Q/A for further information on how to rollback to a previous version of Ubuntu:

---

- [release management - How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49869/36315)

Comment: But the repositories is still disabled either way.

Comment: @Akar This might downgrade your packages, also how did you get it to update to Xenial, its far from finished?

Comment: I have no idea. I just pressed accept or whatever.  The repositories are commented out. with another comment that says "Disabled on upgrade to Xenial".

Comment: In the `Software & Updates` go to the tab `Other Software`, and enable all the Trusty packages, or rename the `xenial` part to `trusty`. Note, this is not recommended, and *might* break your system. **Use at your own risk**. I'd recommended to do a full backup of everything and just do a clean install.

Comment: Alright, I will do it at my own risk. Thanks for your help!